# ThreadPool pass function as argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

I'm trying to implement my own version of parallel for using https://github.com/Fdhvdu/ThreadPool as the backend thread pool

I'm splitting up the task to several slices and launching a thread with the following function:

```
template <typename Callable>
void launchRange(int id, Callable func, int k1, int k2)
{
    for (int k = k1; k < k2; k++) {
        func(k);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is how to pass this `Callable` to the thread pool

The relevant part is:

```
poolPtr->add(launchRange, func, i1, i2);
```

But I keep getting compilation errors. The error is:

```
...\ithreadpoolitembase.hpp(36): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::tuple<conditional<_Test,void(__cdecl *&)(int),_Ty>::type,conditional<_Test,int&,int>::type,conditional<_Test,int&,int>::type>'
with
[
    _Ty=void (__cdecl *)(int)
]
```

The interface for `add` is

```
template<class Func,class ... Args>
inline thread_id add(Func &&func,Args &&...args);
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.4 with `/std:c++17`

Comment: There is a `c++11` tag in the question, but you use `/std:c++17`? Since you are using VS2017, have you tried using functions with [Execution policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism)?

Comment: the `c++17` comment was because the ThreadPool library linked stated that it needs c++17 so I wanted to avoid comments that states that VS2017 15.4 doesn't fully support c++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`launchRange` is a function template not a function.

You cannot pass a function template as a function unless overload resolution has completed.  That line doesn't trigger overload resolution.

```
auto launchRange = [](int id, auto&& func, int k1, int k2)
{
  for (int k = k1; k < k2; k++) {
    func(k);
  }
};
```

the above is a lambda that acts a lot like `launchRange` template does, but it is an actual object, not just a template.

It still won't work because you don't pass `add` the `id` argument.

```
poolPtr->add(launchRange, 77, func, i1, i2);
```

that will probably compile.

I don't particularly like that specific thread pool implementation.  I mean, how many pointless pimpl layers can you have?  How much pointless heap allocation?  And, it *passes by reference by default*, which is a horrible idea when passing stuff to another thread.

I'd argue that taking arguments is a bad plan here.  Avoid using them.

```
poolPtr->add([=]{ launchRange(77, func, i1, i2); });
```

that also eliminates the need to create a `auto launchRange = []` lambda as well.  And errors end up being far easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, It works after applying the lambda to `add`. Regarding your comment, I'm looking for a lightweight thread pool implementation. Can you recommend any?

Comment: @Lablabla [Here is a toy one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53089760/1774667), like 40 lines of code?  Replace `boost::optional` with `std::optional` in C++17.  It could use some cleaning up, I can write a better one now, but I believe it is serviceable.